# Sequential case processing with dynamic logic?

Tags: spss

OK, I've looked at some of the sequential case processing posts and they don't cover my needs.

I actually have a way to do this in Excel, but it requires a macro to run and it takes forever (like days), depending on the amount of data.

OK, here is the scenario.

The data is from a survey, and as it comes in there are a number of data integrity checks. A number of things are validated, and some of the checks are dependent upon previous surveys that pass validation. For example, we might say that only one 'OK' survey is permitted per IP address per some timeframe (like 1 a day).

This happens automatically as data comes in based on the parameters we set for the survey.

My need arises when trying to re-validate surveys based on different parameters (basically to simulate how data might change). So, if I turn off a validation check, and a particular case might become 'OK', that might affect another case from the same IP address taken later, but previously wouldn't have because it wasn't 'OK'.

My current solution in Excel is a row of IF(COUNTIFS()>0) formulas looking at previous cases. My macro loops through an array, and copies the row of formulas down line-by-line so each case is calculated sequentially.

This works, but when running it on hundreds of thousands of lines of data, it takes a while (and i have a fairly beefy computer).

Is there a way to process cases sequentially like this in SPSS?

Comment: This sounds like an interesting problem to work on, and I have no doublt we can help with your problem. BUT you have to focus your question more, and add some sample data or at least a more thorough description of it, otherwise the answers won't get more specific than @JKP's.

Answer (score 1):

The devil is in the details, but you can reference previous cases relative to the current case with the LAG function or the SHIFT VALUES procedure.  The lag parameter is fixed, however.  Using AGGREGATE breaking by the IP address might also be helpful here.